# Probability space $\Omega$ with multiple $\sigma$ - algebras

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question relating $\sigma$ - algebras. If there is a probability space $\Omega$ then $\sigma$ algebra is a set consisting of subsets of $\Omega$. There can be a $\sigma $ algebra that doesn't represent all possible subsets of $\Omega$, but then the definition of closed under complement, means that all the complements of elements in $\sigma$ algebra also belong to $\sigma $ algebra. But if there can be multiple $\sigma$ algebras to one probability space $\Omega$ then how can complement even be defined?

Comment: Complement of a set $A$ is $A^c := \{\omega \in \Omega : \omega \notin A\}$; why does this have any conflict with the idea that there can be different $\sigma$-algebras?. As to how there can be multiple $\sigma$-algebras, perhaps it may help to think of a concrete example. Any $\Omega$ [with at least two elements] has at least two distinct $\sigma$-algebras. The coarsest one is $\{\varnothing, \Omega\}$, while the finest one is the power set of $\Omega$ (all possible subsets).

Comment: @angryavian As I understood it $\omega | \omega \in \Omega$ are elementary events, but $\sigma$ alegbra forms subsets of $\Omega$. For example if $\Omega :=${$\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3$} And $\sigma$ algebra is {{$\omega_1, \omega_2$}$, \omega_1$}, then complacent of this set would be all possible subsets of $\Omega$, that are not elements of this $\sigma$ algebra. And then the $\sigma$ algebra is not closed under complement.

Comment: The condition about complements is not regarding the complement of the $\sigma$-algebra, but rather the complement of each set in the $\sigma$-algebra. In your example of $\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3\}$, if a $\sigma$-algebra contains the set $\{\omega_1, \omega_2\}$, it must also contain the complement $\{\omega_3\}$; if it contains $\{\omega_1\}$, it must also contain the complement $\{\omega_2, \omega_3\}$. Your example $\{\{\omega_1, \omega_2\}, \{\omega_1\}\}$ is not a valid $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @angryavian Would this be a valid $\sigma$ algebra if $\Omega$ is the same as above. $\sigma:=${{$\omega_1$}{$\omega_2,\omega_3$},{$\omega_3$}{$\omega_1,\omega_2$},{$\varnothing$}}?

Comment: No, it also needs to be closed under countable unions. Since you have $\{\omega_1\}$ and $\{\omega_3\}$, you must also have its union $\{\omega_1, \omega_3\}$. In the end you can show that any $\sigma$-algebra containing $\{\omega_1, \omega_2\}$ and $\{\omega_1\}$ must contain all subsets of $\{\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3\}$.

Comment: @user Note also that $\{\varnothing\}\not\in\sigma$ if $\varnothing\not \in\Omega$. The set $\varnothing$ is empty set, and $\{\varnothing\}$ is not empty set.

Comment: @NCh Ok, I thought that $\sigma$ algebra must contain $\varnothing$ as it is closed under intersections, and if there are two subsets of $\sigma$ algebra having no common elements, then there must also be an empty set included in the $\sigma$ algebra set. Maybe it is a must to have an empty set in $\Omega$?